# Equilibrium and energy of: $mr''(t)=\frac{-dU}{dr}r(t)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

I am studying ODE and I am doing exercises from previous exams. I have to study the equilibrium points and the total energy of the system:

$mr''(t)=\frac{-dU}{dr}r(t)$

with $U$ being the Lennard-Jones' potential. I rewrote the equation using $x_1=r(t)$ and $x_2=r'(t)$:

$x'_1=x_2 \\ x'_2 = -\frac{U'(x_1)x_1}{m}.$

Which, I think, is an autonomous system. To compute the equilibria, I simply set to zero the derivatives, obtaining $x_2=0$ and $U'(x_1)x_1=0$. Now, How can I solve the second equation?

Moreover, I need to show that the total energy defined as

$E(x_1,x_2) := \frac{1}{2}(x_2)^2+U(x_1)$,

is a constant of energy. I know that in order to be a constant of energy, $E'=\nabla E \cdot f(y)=0$. But how should I compute it? If I compute the gradient of $E$ and multiply by the RHS of the ODE, what do I get? It is the first time I do such an exercise and I did not find any example in my textbook.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let solve the second equation.

$\; U'(x_1)x_1=0 \implies$

$ U'(x_1)=0 \implies U(x_1)=constant =C $
$\implies E(x_1,x_2)=U(x_1)=C.$

Comment: Thank you. I am not sure I understood what you did. You are trying to compute the second equilibrium point?

Comment: Thank you very much. Have a nice day.

Comment: I have to do some more things. If I want to find the critical points of the energy function, I use the "second derivative test". In this case I obtain the Hessian . But my professor told me that it should not be zero. What is the problem? Thank you.

Comment: Hessian is $U''(x_1)=0$.